# Paylocity API Access using Python

Tags: python, json, api

I need access PTO data for all employees in our organization.

I reached out to Paylocity Support, however they weren't able to help me.

If You had a similar task, could You please share code example how you pulled such data?

The only code I could find:

```
import urllib
import requests
import json

client_id = 'unique_client_id '
client_secret = 'unique_client_secret '
company_id = 'unique_company_id '

prod_auth_url = 'https://api.paylocity.com/IdentityServer/connect/token'

body_params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'grant_type': 'client_credentials','scope':'WebLinkAPI'})

# Requests can use auth= for basic authentication
auth_response = requests.post(prod_auth_url,auth=(client_id, client_secret), data=body_params)
response = auth_response.json()
print(response)
```

The output I got:

{'access_token': **'my_unique_access_token',** 'expires_in': 3600, 'token_type': 'Bearer'}

What is my next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the Paylocity Web Services Representative answer.

[image]